# Prototype inheritance and pointers

Tags: javascript

I am playing with prototypes in javascript and I'm failing to understand some inheritance concepts. Please consider the following code snippets and my questions in comments.

```
function Cat() {
}

Cat.prototype.age = 10;

var cat1 = new Cat(); // cat has age = 10

Cat.prototype = { age: 15 }; // the Cat's prototype is pointing to a new object with age = 15

var cat2 = new Cat(); // cat2 is using the new prototype object, thus having age = 15

display(cat1.age); // will display 10, because cat1 is using the old prototype object
display(cat2.age); // will display 15 because cat2 is using the new prototype object
```

The above example made it clear how the prototype references works. However, the same principle seems to not hold when having inheritance, like shown below.

```
function Animal() {
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
    console.log("Speak 1");
}

function Cat() {
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // creates a new instance of the Animal prototype, Cat.prototype === Animal.prototype is FALSE
var cat1 = new Cat(); // this cat instance uses the prototype created at the above step (right?) and not the actual Animal.prototype

Animal.prototype.speak = function() { // this code changes the 'actual' Animal.prototype instance, NOT cat1's prototype (right?)
    console.log("Speak 2");
}

cat1.speak(); // this displays Speak 2. Why ??
```

Comment: You never changed the Cat's prototype, only added a method to Animal's prototype

Comment: Using `*.prototype = ...` breaks the prototype chain.

Comment: You've got 4 different people explaining why, but no actual solutions, so I gave a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

However, the `speak` property of `cat1` is resolved by checking *up the property chain*. It does *not* use a copy made by `Object.create()` `Object.create` Does not make a copy. See Mozilla:

> The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing
>   object to provide the newly created object's **proto** . (see browser
>   console for visual evidence.)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Note that `Object.create(somePrototype).__proto__ === somePrototype` and that when the property `b` of `a` is resolved, it checks for `a.__proto__.b`, if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you replace the entire prototype object. In the second, your prototype chain remains intact because you don't replace any of the objects; only a property value (the "speak" property) is updated.

The prototype chain consists of the actual prototype objects, not copies of the prototype objects. Updating that "speak" property therefore affects all objects with that object in their prototype chains.

So: after creating `cat1`, this will be true:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(cat1) === Cat.prototype
```

And similarly

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Cat.prototype) === Animal.prototype
```

will also be true. After updating the "speak" property, both of those expressions will *still be true*. Because the prototype chain is exactly the same, the effect is that `cat1.speak()` will call that new function and not the old one.

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

As others have noted, using `Object.assign` or `Object.create` is still going to link to the parent prototype. *The reason is because objects and functions are passed by reference, not value*.

So, while `Object.assign` will create a new instance of the prototype object, the new prototype's methods, in memory, still *reference* the methods of the parent object.

This is breifly explained on [MDN's Functions page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> However, object references are values, too, and they are special: if
>   the function changes the referred object's properties, that change is
>   visible outside the function, as shown in the following example.

---

### Solution

You can, if you want, manually create an actual copy of each of the parent prototype's methods with the `Function` constructor, thus creating methods that do not reference the parent's prototype's methods.

```
Function.prototype.extends = function(parent){
  for(let p in parent.prototype){
    let f = parent.prototype[p].toString().replace(/\r/g, '');
    let params = (f.match(/function.*\((.*)\)/)||['',''])[1].split(',').map(p=>p.trim());
    var body = f.match(/{(?:\n|.)*}/)[0].slice(1,-1);
    this.prototype[p] = Function(...params, body);
  }
}
```

Which you then employ by simply calling...

```
Cat.extends(Animal);
```

After doing so, you can freely change the `Animal` prototype without it affecting the `Cat` prototype, and vice versa..

---

### Example

```js
Function.prototype.extends = function(parent) {
  for (let p in parent.prototype) {
    let f = parent.prototype[p].toString().replace(/\r/g, '');
    let params = (f.match(/function.*\((.*)\)/) || ['', ''])[1].split(',').map(p => p.trim());
    var body = f.match(/{(?:\n|.)*}/)[0].slice(1, -1);
    this.prototype[p] = Function(...params, body);
  }
}

function Animal() {}

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
  console.log("Speak 1");
}

function Cat() {}

// Do inheritence
Cat.extends(Animal);

var cat1 = new Cat();

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
  console.log("Speak 2");
}

cat1.speak();
new Animal().speak();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example - You never changed the `Cat`'s *prototype* (or the `Animal`'s *prototype*), only added a method to `Animal`'s prototype which was already linked to `Cat`'s *prototype*.

So more appropriate analogy to your first example would be,

```js
function Animal() {
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
    console.log("Speak 1");
}

function Cat() {
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); 
var cat1 = new Cat(); 

Animal.prototype = { speak : function(){ console.log(3) } }


cat1.speak(); //speak 1 as older Animal's prototpye will still be linked
```

Comment: @DimitarTsonev Yes, however you didn't changed the reference to Animal's prototype in your second example like you did in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue regarding to memory reference rather than prototype chaining, Etc Etc.

See the comments and the printed logs after executing this code snippet.

```js
function Animal() {
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
    console.log("Speak 1");
}

function Cat() {
}

// You have created a new object wich property 'speak' is pointing to the same function
// in Animal.prototype.speak
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

//Same memory reference
console.log("Pointing to same function in memory:", Cat.prototype.speak === Animal.prototype.speak);

var cat1 = new Cat();

// Here you're changing Cat.protype.speak as well, because 
// both prototypes are pointing to the same function 'speak'
Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log("Speak 2");
}
console.log('After assiging a new function speak')
console.log("Pointing to same function in memory:", Cat.prototype.speak === Animal.prototype.speak);


cat1.speak(); // this displays Speak 2. Why ??
```